# How to re-index single product programmatically?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

How to so index of single product?
I have tried below code but it's not working.

`Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->processEntityAction( $product, Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, Mage_Index_Model_Event::TYPE_SAVE )`

is there any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do product indexing by their attribute like this:

```
$indexer = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->processEntityAction($_product, 'catalog_url', Mage_Index_Model_Event::TYPE_SAVE);
```

Hope, it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$process = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessByCode("cataloginventory_stock");
$process->reindexAll();
```

Try use this codes depending do you need:

```
catalog_product_attribute     Product Attributes
catalog_product_price         Product Prices
catalog_url                   Catalog Url Rewrites
catalog_product_flat          Product Flat Data
catalog_category_flat         Category Flat Data
catalog_category_product      Category Product
catalogsearch_fulltext        Catalog Search Index
cataloginventory_stock        Stock status
```

Comment: thank you. i wanted only product reindex. but its nice, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app();
$childIds = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getChildrenIds('121644');
$productsIds = $childIds;
$event = Mage::getModel('index/event');
$event->setNewData(array(
'product_ids' => $productsIds,));
Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/category_indexer_product')->catalogProductMassAction($event);
Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_indexer_price')->reindexProductIds($productsIds);
Mage::getResourceModel('cataloginventory/indexer_stock')->reindexProducts($productsIds);
Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_indexer_eav_source')->reindexEntities($productsIds);
$catalogSearchIndexer = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogsearch/fulltext');
$catalogSearchIndexer->rebuildIndex(null, $productsIds);
echo "Done";exit;
```